# Android open phone call application

Tags: android, launch, launcher, phone-call

I just want to open phone call application of android device. I dont want to provide that application a phone number. Just want to open it.
 I am using phone application's package name to open it. Because I am able to open any application I want through that package name with the code below.
`Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.contacts");
                startActivity(launchIntent);`

I am not able to open **Phone** and **Contacts** application with the above code. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Intents` are intended (no pwn intended here (damn!)) to give you a more generic way of accessing actions such as opening a file. If you had to specify the package of whatever you wanted to do this would be very limited. However, here are some of the intents that may be what you're after.

```
//For the contacts (picking one)
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
//For the contacts (viewing them) 
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
//For the dial pad
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, null);
//For viewing the call log
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
```

Make yourself a `useful intents` file somewhere to save you time in the future, you'll thank me later someday.

Of course to start those intents you'd do `startActivity(i);` for all excepting the first one, since you'd want the contact back and you'd need `startActivityForResult(i);` but that's another story.

Comment: I dont want to pick a call. I just want to open native phone call.

Comment: Have you even tried them? Because if you did, you'd have seen that they work.

Comment: ACTION_DIAL does work but I wanted to open that using package name. If I use one of your methods I need to hard code it to open Phone and contacts app which is bad. I can open any application I want with package name except these two apps. Try my code...

Comment: So, what you want is to open _any_ application by package name, only these two do not work? Is that right? Then what's the errormessage?

Answer (score 2):

> public static final String ACTION_DIAL
>
> Since: API Level 1 Activity Action: Dial a number as specified by the
>   data. This shows a UI with the number being dialed, allowing the user
>   to explicitly initiate the call. **Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is
>   started;**

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL could be also what you are looking for.

If you want to start the phone call from an Activity, just use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent) from the Activity's Context.