# Application unfortunately stop in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on my app to start another app. It's work perfectly. but when i start a **phone app(call log)** it unfortunately stop. This is a system app. 
Here is my code for start new app.

```
Intent launchIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Logcat Output

```
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352): Process: com.demo.applicationbackup, PID: 22352
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1484)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3436)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3393)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at web.revolution.applicationbackup.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:182)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-07 15:27:30.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22352):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Good answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732641/android-open-phone-call-application

Comment: Great!! Give him one vote. He deserves. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of launching the native phone app using package manager you can use a better `Intent`  to open call logs. Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope it helps.